# Url.RouteUrl in js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

I have a situation that I need to jump urls in javascript of a ASP.NET MVC site.

As we know, we can generate url with @Url.RouteUrl("RouteName", new { params}) in xx.cshtml. Now I want to generate url in the same way in javascript, is it possible?

I have tried:

window.location.href ='@Url.RouteUrl("RouteName", new {param1="' + param+ '"}) %>'.

However, it doesn't work.

My Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "ListOfTicketAB",
            "piao/{citystart}-{cityend}",
            new { controller = "Tickets", action = "ListS2S", traintype = 0, sorttype = 0, page = 1 },
            new { citystart = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+", cityend = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+" });
```

My js:

```
var selectS;var selectE;function SearchClick(obj) {

        location.href = '@Url.RouteUrl("ListOfTicketAB",new {citystart="' + selectS+ '",cityend="' + selectE+ '"})';

}
```

selectS and selectE will be set in some other functions.

With Above, I got error:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Illegal characters in path. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: what is the url in web browser you got while above Error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to generate url in the same way in javascript, is it possible?

No, javascript files cannot execute server side Razor language.

What you could do is generate this url as a global javascript variable in your view or as HTML5 data-* attribute to some existing DOM element that you could access later in your javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myUrl = '@Url.RouteUrl("ListOfTicketAB", new { citystart = "_start_", cityend = "_end_" })';
</script>
```

and then in your javascript replace the 2 placeholders with the corresponding values of your existing javascript variables `selectS` and `selectE`:

```
var selectS;
var selectE;

function SearchClick(obj) {
    var url = myUrl.replace('_start_', selectS).replace('_end_', selectE);
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Darin. Your suggestion seems a good idea. I tried to implement it in my code. But it always generate myUrl as empty. I debug into it, the Url.RouteUrl tells me that "Expression cannot contain anonymous types" because of the routevalue code{new { citystart = "_start_", cityend = "_end_" } }. How to figure it out?

Comment: Cant u pass the url generated in razor page to this function like SearchClick(obj,myUrl); @PaulZhou

Comment: The problem is that I cant generate myUrl, it is empty always because I got "Expression cannot contain anonymous types" when I use Url.RouteUrl to generate myUrl